# В Ubuntu gparted live не видит дополнительное неразмеченное пространство

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, gparted

На VirtualBox установил Ubuntu 20.04.4. Диск VDI динамический. Изначально было 10 Гб. Сейчас захотел увеличить.
Открыл в VirtualBox "менеджер виртуальных носителей" и увеличил размер vdi-диска до 16 Гб:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее запускаю саму виртуаку и открываю программу GParted. Судя по скриншотам из интернета я должен там увидеть дополнительно созданный объём. И затем увеличить диск на этот объём. Но он не отображается. Т.е. дополнительных 6 Гб я просто не вижу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем прочитал, что загружаться надо не как обычно, а с помощью Live CD. Добавил в оптический привод iso-образ и загрузился как live cd. Открыл GParted - аналогично, доп. пространство диска не отображается. Также попробал открыть утилиту Disks - тоже самое.

Затем где-то нагуглил, что есть live-образ самой проги GParted. В итоге скачал несколько разных версий:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал все 3 по очереди. Результат аналогичный.
На хосте установлена Kubuntu 22.04, версия VirtualBox 6.1
Подскажите, что я делаю неправильно?

Возможно есть способ увидеть искомые 6 Гб и увеличить диск через терминал?

Comment: может вы не тот диск увеличили или забыли нажать применить, тока что проделал подобные операции и всё отлично получилось

Comment: @Zt.   не знаю, это осталось загадкой )))  Потратил на это 2 дня, но ничего не заработало. В итоге просто создал новую виртуальную машину, и сразу указал 50 Гб, чтобы с запасом было.